# Drawing dynamic lines in java applets using JAVA AWT mousemotionlistener?

Tags: java, applet

So, here is the thing. My lecturer taught us how to get mouse coordinates by clicking on an applet. Now, i was thinking that may be i can try drawing dynamic lines using mousemotionlistener class using the mousedrag method and the mouse coordinates. I tried it but couldn't really make it work. Can anyone please suggest me where i made the error. Thanks a lot.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.applet.*;

public class drawing extends Applet
implements MouseMotionListener {  

    int mx,my;
    Graphics2D g2;

    public void init()
    {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        this.setSize(800,600);

         g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
         g2.drawLine(40,50,200,150); // I was experimenting to draw static lines using the drawLine() method. 
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mx = e.getX();
        my = e.getY();
        System.out.println(" "+ mx + " "+ my);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.drawLine(mx,my,mx,my); 



    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to draw a line, you need to know the start point (which would be the point the user clicked) and the end point (the point where the user dragged to), from there is a simple matter to simple use `Graphics#drawLine`.

Start by taking a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Drawing extends Applet
                implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    private Point startPoint, endPoint;

    public void init() {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (startPoint != null && endPoint != null) {
            g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        endPoint = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        startPoint = e.getPoint();
        endPoint = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Now, my advice, don't use `Applet` or AWT directly.  Instead, start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and use it perform your custom painting.  Then add this panel to a `JFrame` to display it on the screen.

AWT is more then 15 years out of date and applets have way to many gotchas which you just don't need to deal with right now.

Start by having a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or even do some research into JavaFX

Comment: :- Thanks a lot for your reply. It helped me a lot. When i draw a line on the applet and i try to draw it again, My initial line gets erased. How can i stop that?

Comment: :- Fixed it. I read the documentation and understood how the repaint() method works. So, i had to to overwrite the update method to call the paint method. Also, i have a question, whenever i try to create something innovative, i get stuck halfway and post my question in StackOverflow. Does it mean that i cannot be a good programmer as i always somehow end up asking for help?

Comment: To your first problem, you should be storing the `Point`s in a array or `List` of some kind, then when the program is painted, simply loop over the array or `List` and redraw the lines.  The single line rendering was a deliberate choice on my part.  Painting is destructive and you are expected to repaint the entire state of the component each time.  To your second problem, no, it means you simply lack experience and it happens to use all.  I've been teaching myself iOS over the past few months and what would be simple for me to do in Java takes a much longer time in iOS - because of experience